# How do I develop this login interface?

Tags: java, loops, authentication, arraylist, netbeans

I got a list(Employees) of employees(object of class Employee) and I try to iterate over that list so I can validate the entered information otherwise rise a message error, It does validate the information and logins in when right information but it raises an error in all others employees checked existent in the list.

```
    String username = FieldUsername.getText();
    String password = FieldPassword.getText();

    Iterator<Employee> i = Employees.iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Employee o = i.next();

        if (o.getName().equals(username) & o.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            if (o.getJob().equals("President")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
                UserPresident uno = new UserPresident();
                uno.show();
                this.dispose();
            } else if (o.getJob().equals("Manager")) {
                if (o.getArea().equals("Production")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
                    UserProductionManager uno = new UserProductionManager();
                    uno.show();
                }else if(o.getArea().equals("Marketing")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
                    UserMarketingManager uno = new UserMarketingManager();
                    uno.show();
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
                    UserHRManager uno = new UserHRManager();
                    uno.show();
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido");
                UserEmployee uno = new UserEmployee();
                uno.show();
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username or password is incorrect!");
            FieldUsername.setText("");
            FieldPassword.setText("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add a more detailed information on the error that you are getting, also could you include some information on the Employee class

Comment: @Colby Quinn, sorry I didn't mean an "error", I'm getting the message dialog "username or password is incorrect" in my else statement, which is only suppose to show up when it is incorrect, but it shows up as many times as employees in the list even if logins in with a correct username and password, I mean there are 5 employees in the list and 1 is correct then, it logins in and then it shows "username or password incorrect" 4 times as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will go through each and every employee even if it is correct login it continues to look for another employee to match, you need to make it print **Username or password is incorrect!** after the loop is done and it hasn't found a match, you could do this by adding a boolean value before the loop and if a correct user was found then change the boolean to not print the **Username or password is incorrect!**, a simple example:

```
String username = FieldUsername.getText();
String password = FieldPassword.getText();

Iterator<Employee> i = Employees.iterator();

boolean isCorrectLoginFound = false // Checks for correct login

while (i.hasNext()) {
    Employee o = i.next();
    if (o.getName().equals(username) && o.getPassword().equals(password)) {

        isCorrectLoginFound = true;

        if (o.getJob().equals("President")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
            UserPresident uno = new UserPresident();
            uno.show();
            this.dispose();
            break;
        } else if (o.getJob().equals("Manager")) {
            if (o.getArea().equals("Production")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
                UserProductionManager uno = new UserProductionManager();
                uno.show();
                break;
            }else if(o.getArea().equals("Marketing")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
                UserMarketingManager uno = new UserMarketingManager();
                uno.show();
                break;
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
                UserHRManager uno = new UserHRManager();
                uno.show();
                break;
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido");
            UserEmployee uno = new UserEmployee();
            uno.show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (!isCorrectLoginFound) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username or password is incorrect!");
   FieldUsername.setText("");
   FieldPassword.setText("");
}
```